# Postgresql error:cannot change data type of view column from character varying(20) to character varying

Tags: postgresql

How do you merge / cast different type of character varying column with `CASE WHEN` ?

```
    CASE WHEN (DATE_PART('Year',io.movementdate) >= 2024) AND (COALESCE(bp.x_taxid,'') <> '') THEN bp.x_taxid::character varying
        ELSE bp.taxid::character varying
    END AS taxid,
```

this gave me error :
SQL Error [42P16]: ERROR: cannot change data type of view column "taxid" from character varying(20) to character varying
ERROR: cannot change data type of view column "taxid" from character varying(20) to character varying

How to solve this ?

I just tried to cast each column with character varying but no luck.

Comment: Drop the current view and create the new version. You can do this within a single transaction